# Removing the white space from between images

Tags: css

I want to display 3 images per 1 row with html and css.
I have the following code to display the images

```css
.articles {
  margin: 100px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.article {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.article-image {
  padding-left: 480px;
  padding-top: 1073px;
}

.article-title {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #3f3f3f;
  font-family: "SFUI Display";
  padding-left: 520px;
}
```

```html
<article class="article">
  <img class="article-image" src="/images/6-0-article.png">
  <h3 class="article-title">Article 1 </h3>
  <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
              </label>
</article>

<article class="article">
  <img class="article-image" src="/images/6-0-article.png">
  <h3 class="article-title">Article 1 </h3>
  <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
              </label>
</article>
```

So how could I accomplish for them to be side-by-side?

Comment: This code is irrelevant. Show how you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: How it is irrelevant? The code is related to how I display the images.